# The chord of contact of the pair the tangents to the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ drawn from any point $2x+y=4$ pass through the point

Tags: conic-sections

Let the point be (h,k)

Therefore 
$$2h+k=4$$ and $$hx+ky=1$$

How do I solve further? Are these lines coincident? If so, why?

Comment: y^1 are you sure? you mean y^2?

Comment: Which point to you mean? The common intersection that you’re meant to find can’t lie on the given line since you can find a point on it for which the chord of contact is parallel to the line.

Comment: I think your question is wrong.there is no such a circle like y^2+x^1=1 as i think you observe y^2+x^2=1

Comment: https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/the-chords-of-contact-of-the-pair-of-tangents-drawn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you are missing from any external point (X1,Y1) if tangents are dran to the circle X^2 + Y^2= 1 , this equality holds good X*X1 + Y*Y1 = 1. Hope this helps[image]